# Delete rows in PySpark dataframe based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe with a structure similar to the following:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
A,A,A,A
A,B,C,D
B,C,A,D
A,C,A,D
A,F,A,A
A,V,B,A
```

What I want is to 'drop' the rows where conditions are met for all columns at the same time. For example, drop rows where `col1 == A` and `col2 == C` at the same time. Note that, in this case, the only row that should be dropped would be `"A,C,A,D"` as it's the only one where both conditions are met at the same time. Hence, the dataframe should look like this:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
A,A,A,A
A,B,C,D
B,C,A,D
A,F,A,A
A,V,B,A
```

What I've tried so far is:

```
# spark library import
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.filter(
               ((F.col("col1") != "A") & (F.col("col2") != "C"))
               )
```

This one doesn't filter as I want, because it removes all rows where only one condition is met, like`col1 == "A"` or `col2 == "C"`, returning:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
B,C,A,D
```

Can anybody please help me out with this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to break the filtering

`df = df.filter(((F.col("col1") != "A")).filter(F.col("col2") != "C")))`

Comment: Seems like you are doing everything right. Maybe try to make it a single text expression `.filter("col1 != 'A' and col2 != 'C'")`

Comment: @go2nirvana I've tried  it doesn't work :(

Comment: @Vaebhav I've tried your approach, but it gives me an error

Comment: @marsolmos could you then provide sample of a real dataframe that you work with and also the exact code that does the filtering.

Comment: Can you please check if the underlaying solution works for you ? Will really appriciate if you could help accept  and upvote @marsolmos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
df.withColumn('Result',when(df.col1!='A',"True").when(df.col2!='C',"True")).filter("Result==True").drop("Result").show()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 5):

Combine both conditions and do a `NOT`:

```
cond = (F.col('col1') == 'A') & (F.col('col2') == 'C')

df.filter(~cond)
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Not sure why it's not accepted

Answer (score 0):

This can be a working solution for you - use **`when()`** condition and create a column based on the condition you wish for

## Create the DF Here

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("A", "A", "A", "A"),("A", "B", "C", "D"),("B", "C", "A", "D"),("A", "C", "A", "D"), ("A", "F", "A", "A"), ("A", "V", "B", "A")],[ "col1","col2", "col3", "col4"])
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|A   |A   |A   |A   |
|A   |B   |C   |D   |
|B   |C   |A   |D   |
|A   |C   |A   |D   |
|A   |F   |A   |A   |
|A   |V   |B   |A   |
+----+----+----+----+
```

## When Condition as

```
df = df.withColumn("filter_col", F.when(((F.col("col1") == F.lit("A")) & (F.col("col2") == F.lit("C"))), F.lit("1")))
df.show()
+----+----+----+----+----------+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|filter_col|
+----+----+----+----+----------+
|   A|   A|   A|   A|      null|
|   A|   B|   C|   D|      null|
|   B|   C|   A|   D|      null|
|   A|   C|   A|   D|         1|
|   A|   F|   A|   A|      null|
|   A|   V|   B|   A|      null|
+----+----+----+----+----------+
```

## Filter out the row now

```
df = df.filter(F.col("filter_col").isNull()).select("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4")
df.show()
   +----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|   A|   A|   A|   A|
|   A|   B|   C|   D|
|   B|   C|   A|   D|
|   A|   F|   A|   A|
|   A|   V|   B|   A|
+----+----+----+----+
```